# React Native IAP: getPurchaseHistory() throws error if sandbox account isn't previously signed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

This is for iOS. I'm using in-app purchases in my React Native app, and I use the following code:

```
     IAP.initConnection()
        .catch((e) => {   
          throwError(`Error connecting to the in-app purchase store: ${e}`)})
        .then(async () => {
          await IAP.getPurchaseHistory()
            .catch(e => throwError(`Errors fetching purchase history: ${e}`))
            .then(async (receipt) => {
              validate(receipt)
            });
        });
```

If I'm not already signed into a sandbox account Apple ID, calling `IAP.getPurchaseHistory` prompts the user to sign in. If I do, then `IAP.getPurchaseHistory()` always throws an error.

Has anyone encountered this?